# How to disable 3rd party app tray icons/indicators in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell, system-tray

Would love to disable 3rd party app tray icons in Ubuntu 18.10, cause on HiDPi screen they look ugly - [image: Screenshot]

Heard that removing `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` might take care of it, but it also wants to remove `ubuntu-desktop*` packages with it, so I wont even try it.

Tried also an extension called https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/ but it does not work as expected. It did hide the pointed app tray icon, but when you run the app again, another tray icon entry was created. I wont waste my time hiding new tray icons every time I launch an app.

I also don't want to install `gnome vanilla`. There must be a file/setting in the system somewhere that controls app indicators.

So any fix making app indicators disappear will be highly appreciated.

My system:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.10 x86_64 
Kernel: 4.18.0-15-generic 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 
Resolution: 3840x2160 
DE: GNOME 3.30.1 
WM: GNOME Shell 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-6700K (8) @ 4.300GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 
Memory: 2790MiB / 32101MiB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happy to share a solution to this problem.
File responsible for app indicators is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js`
So, simply make a backup of it - `appIndicator.js.BAK` = no more ugly indicators.
**And don't forget to restart the machine/session for changes to take effect ;)**
The only downside of disabling it will be up to you to configure your apps to not show the tray icons and not interact with it.
And a proof...
[image]

Comment: This should work fine, but note that since `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` is a pre-installed system package (and also a part of the `ubuntu-desktop` metapacakge), any update to the package would reverse this change. So you'll have to this once again.

Comment: Yes, u will have to re-apply the hack.
You can more/less automate it with proper bash script, like almost any workaround in Linux.