# How do I tidy up my top bar?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, top-bar

My top bar looks like this:

[image]

I want the keyboard language and the universal access one, but I don't want the Snapcraft (orange), Bluetooth, or Discord (far left) icons.

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Hide app indicator or similar gnome shell extension is available.

Comment: @UnKNOWn That requires an extension?? I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119077/how-to-disable-3rd-party-app-tray-icons-indicators-in-ubuntu-18-10) but I'm not entirely happy with it because in the future I might want some indicators.

Comment: Seems you need to disable ubuntu-app indicator extension